# How to translate internal CodeIgniter error messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, translation

I am currently looking for a way to translate CI's internal error messages.
For example: "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters."

CI uses the "show_error"-function and provides the full error message.

But in my case, i want to have the german (or whatever language is set) translation of that error displayed to the user.
How can i achieve that (if even possible) in a smart way, without some "hacky" stuff?

Comment: here is example and repo https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations

Comment: Thanks, but thats not what i am looking for

Comment: i recommend you to download German language and put it in your project like @PHPNinja said

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

Calls to `show_error` do not use the translation files.

I think it is because they are internal errors that will not be seen by the end user. They are only messages for developers.

To translate the default heading parameter, I implemented in my helper a function `translate_show_error`.

```
function tranlated_show_error($message, $status_code = 500, $heading = '') {
    if ('' === $heading) {
        $heading = lang('error_enconteured');
    }
    show_error($message, $status_code, $heading);
}
```